# Get one value in object array and put in single array php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make an object array into a single array whose value is taken from one of the object's values. For example, I have an object array like below.

```
[
  {
    "stockname": 12,
    "stockname": "BREAD"
  },
  {
    "stockname": 13,
    "stockname": "PEANUT"
  }
]
```

And the result I want is like this by taking the stockid value

```
[12,13]
```

I've read various references but still haven't found a solution in php

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach to manually create an array based on object values.

```php
$objects = [
  {
    "stock": 12,
    "stockname": "BREAD"
  },
  {
    "stock": 13,
    "stockname": "PEANUT"
  }
];

$stocks = [];

foreach ($objects as $obj) {
  array_push($stocks, $obj->stock);
}
```